# How can I create a dependent validation rule in Nova?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I have fields defined as the following for a resource in Nova:

```
Select::make('Type')
    ->options([
        'video' => 'Video',
        'download' => 'Download',
        ])
    ->rules('required'),    

File::make('File', 'file_name')
    ->disk('local')
    ->path('/files')
```

I am trying to setup different validation rules for the File field depending on the value of the type field.  For example where the type is download accept document mimes and a max size of 1mb, whilst if set as video accept video file mimes and max size of 30mb.

I haven't really got anywhere with trying to achieve this.

I've looked through [the docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/validation.html) and neither [validation rule objects](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#using-rule-objects) or [custom closure rules](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#using-closures) will help me as I wont be able to access the value of the type field from them.

Similarly, I thought of extending the NovaRequest object as one might do with a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation), but this wouldn't do the front-end validation that Nova applies.

Is there any way to achieve this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now have this working through the tutorial provided [here](https://johnbeales.com/2019/formrequest-object-validation-for-laravel-nova-resources/) from John Beales who is similarly complaining that Nova doesn't pick up on Laravel Form Requests automatically.

**1: Create a Request for the Nova Resource that extends FormRequest:**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;


class StoreResourceRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // Users authorized to make the request are:
        // - users updating themselves.
        // - staff
        // - guests creating a new user.


        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        $rules = self::ruleGetter($this);


        if(empty($this->user())) {
            $rules = array_merge_recursive($rules, self::creationRuleGetter($this));
        } else {
            $rules = array_merge_recursive($rules, self::updateRuleGetter($this));
        }

        return $rules;
    }

    public static function ruleGetter( $request, $rule = null ) {

        $rules = [
            'type' =>  ['required',Rule::in(['video', 'download'])],
        ];

        if($request['type'] == 'download'){
            $rules['file_name'] = ['required','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,doc,docx,pdf','max:1000'];
        } 

        if($request['type'] == 'video'){
            $rules['file_name'] = ['required','mimes:mp4','max:50000'];
        }

        if(!empty($rule)) {
            if(isset($rules[$rule])) {
                return $rules[$rule];
            }
            return '';
        }
        return $rules;
    }

    public static function creationRuleGetter( $request, $rule = null ) {
        $rules = [

        ];


        if(!empty($rule)) {
            if(isset($rules[$rule])) {
                return $rules[$rule];
            }
            return '';
        }
        return $rules;

    }

    public static function updateRuleGetter( $request, $rule = null ) {


        $rules = [

        ];

        if(!empty($rule)) {
            if(isset($rules[$rule])) {
                return $rules[$rule];
            }
            return '';
        }
        return $rules;
    }

}
```

**2: Update Nova Resource to load these rules:**

```
namespace App\Nova;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreResourceRequest;

//...

public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        //...

        Select::make('Type')
        ->options([
            'video' => 'Video',
            'download' => 'Download',
        ])
        ->rules(StoreResourceRequest::ruleGetter($request, 'type')),

        File::make('File', 'file_name')
        ->rules(StoreResourceRequest::ruleGetter($request, 'file_name'))

    ];
}
```

The above works for both types of validation and stores the correct value in the database.  Nova can interact with the file normally.

It's just a pity this isn't built in to Nova and the validation logic has to be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use a greate package name nova-dependency-container. You can read the way to use it at novapackage. Notes:

- Change file php.ini line `upload_max_filesize=2M` to `upload_max_filesize=30M`
- Define mimes type with reference this link: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Here is my Document Nova Resource code. Happy coding, ask me if you need!

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\File;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Select;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
use Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\HasDependencies;
use Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\NovaDependencyContainer;

class Document extends Resource
{
    use HasDependencies;
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = 'App\Document';

    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'id';

    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [
        'id',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Select::make('Type','type')
            ->options([
                'video' => 'Video',
                'download' => 'Download',
                ])
            ->rules('required'),
            NovaDependencyContainer::make([
                File::make('Video File','file_name')
                ->storeOriginalName('file_name')
                ->rules('required','mimes:mpga,mp2,mp2a,mp3,m2a,m3a,mp4,flv','max:30000')  //unit max is Kb
            ])->dependsOn('type', 'video'),
            NovaDependencyContainer::make([
                File::make('Document File', 'file_name')
                ->storeOriginalName('file_name')
                ->rules('required','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,doc,docx,pdf','max:1000') 
            ])->dependsOn('type', 'download'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cards available for the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the lenses available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function lenses(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the actions available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Updates:

With problem: “When I'm using your code it works for uploading videos (because that comes first) but then uploading a document gives error that must be a video mimetype as listed. Whether document or video is selected; video rules are applied.”

To solve: Use virtual attributes in model, called [Laravel mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators), I heard it some days ago. See my below codes:

```
// Model Laravel: app\Document.php
class Document extends Model
{
    public function getFileNameVideoAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->type == "video") {
            return $this->file_name;
        }
        return;
    }
    public function setFileNameVideoAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['file_name'] = $value;
    }
    public function getFileNameDocumentAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->type == "download") {
            return $this->file_name;
        }
        return;
    }
    public function setFileNameDocumentAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['file_name'] = $value;
    }
}
// Model Nova: app\Nova\Document.php
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Select::make('Type','type')
            ->options([
                'video' => 'Video',
                'download' => 'Download',
                ])
            ->rules('required'),
            NovaDependencyContainer::make([
                File::make('Video File','file_name_video')
                ->storeOriginalName('file_name')
                ->rules('required','mimes:mpga,mp2,mp2a,mp3,m2a,m3a,mp4,flv','max:30000')  //unit max is Kb
            ])->dependsOn('type', 'video'),
            NovaDependencyContainer::make([
                File::make('Document File', 'file_name_document')
                ->storeOriginalName('file_name')
                ->rules('required','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,doc,docx,pdf','max:1000') 
            ])->dependsOn('type', 'download'),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: This works on the front end - however the validation rules are only applied from the first File input - i.e. even if download field is shown the validation rules require it to be a video.  I assume this is because they have the same input names

Comment: Yes, I tested. It can upload a mp3 file or a pdf file! If you want to more files upload, add them into the nova-dependency-container!

Comment: When I'm using your code it works for uploading videos (because that comes first) but then uploading a document gives error that must be a video mimetype as listed.  Whether document or video is selected; video rules are applied.

Comment: Thanks for keeping going with this!  This approach stores the correct value in the database but no validation at all is applied and Nova is unable to edit/download/delete the file once created (as it is trying for /file_name_video and /file_name_document rather than /file_name)